# Celery randomly fails silently when handling tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django project that uses Celery to run background tasks and scheduled tasks (via Celery Beat). It runs fine locally but has some intermittent problems in production. This is the difficult part, 50% of the time the task completes as expected but the other 50%, it 'fails' silently. The numerous scheduled tasks complete without issue.

## Version details

```
django = "==2.2.4"
celery = "==4.4.6"

python_version = "3.6"
```

Here's a simplified example of the code:

## models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    is_actioned = models.BooleanField(default=False...)
    # Other fields...

    def create_lead(self):
        Lead.objects.create(....)

    def create_something_else(self):
        # Add M2M records, for example: lead.add(obj)

    def handle_task(self):
        self.create_lead()
        self.create_something_else()
        # Make various API calls
    
    def action(self):
        self.handle_task()
        self.is_actioned = True
        self.save()
```

## tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def action_task(task_id):
    tasks = Task.objects.get(id=task_id)
    task.action()
```

## views.py

```
# Call the task
action_task.delay(task.id)
```

## Procfile

```
web: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 myproj.asgi:application
worker: celery worker --app=myproj.celery -l debug
beat: celery beat --app=myproj.celery -l info
```

When viewing the logs a failed task does not appear to be received by the worker.

The strange part is Celery seems to 'select' which methods to fail/skip. For example, `Task.create_lead` will be called successfully but `Task.create_something_else` will not be called. However, `self.is_actioned = True` will always run without fail. I would expect this to 'stop' at which ever point in the code it failed at and not to run `self.is_actioned = True`.

I have checked the server memory usage and it sits around 73% with the odd spike up to 81% (this seems a little high?). CPU averages between 1% and 5% with the odd spike up to 30%. When `action_task` is successfully completed, it takes anywhere between 5 and 7 seconds to execute (according to the worker logs).

`action_task` will fail but then, without intervention/server restarts from myself, the next time it is called (`action_task.delay(task.id)`) will work as expected. Any help or pointers in how to fix or better debug this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a memory issue after all. After doubling the available RAM on the server (and the CPU cores which are now barely getting above 5% usage when under load), the memory usage now sits around 40% give or take 10%. With the additional memory, the Celery processes have been running without issue for around 2 weeks.

Hope this helps anyone with similar issues!